# Let $f(x)$ be non-constant, twice differentiable function define on $\mathbb R$ such that $y=f(x)$ is symmetric about line $x=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, rolles-theorem

> > Let $f(x)$ be non-constant, twice differentiable function define on $\mathbb R$ such that $y=f(x)$ is symmetric about line $x=1$  and $f(-1)=f'(\frac{1}{4})=f'(\frac{1}{2})=0$ then which of the following statements is\are correct

(A) $f''(x)=0$ has atleast four roots in the interval $(0,2)$

(B) $\int_{-2}^{2} (x^5+x^3)f(1+x)<\int_0^2 \frac{1}{1+2^{f(x)}}$

(C) There exist at least one $c\in (\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4})$, such that $f'(c)+cf''(c)=0$

(d) for some $c\in(1,\frac{3}{2}), f'(c)=cf''(c)$

**My Approach:**

Option (A)

since $f(x)$ is symmetric about $x=1$

$\implies$ $f(1+x)=f(1-x)$$\quad$.......$(1)$

and by property of continuous symmetric function $f'(1)=0$

**Now Differentiating equation $(1)$**

$f'(1+x)=-f'(1-x)$$\quad$.... $(2)$

After substituting $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{3}{4}$ in above equation $(2)$ I obtained

$\implies$ $f'(\frac{3}{2})=-f'(\frac{1}{2})=0$ and $f'(\frac{7}{4})=-f'(\frac{1}{4})=0$

So overall

$\implies$ $f'(1)=f'(\frac{1}{2})=f'(\frac{3}{2})=f'(\frac{1}{4})=f'(\frac{7}{4})=0$

Since $f'(x)=0$ has minimum $5$ roots in $(0,2)$ so $f''(x)=0$ will have at least **four** roots in $(0,2)$

Option (B)

Clearly Left side Integral is $0$ because it is an odd function and right side integral will be **positive**

Option (C)

for $c\in (\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4})$ $f''(c)=0$ at least once but $f'(c)$ may not be zero

Option (D)

I am not sure how to solve this option.

I tried using LMVT but I didn't arrive at the result.

**My doubts**

(1) How to solve option (D)

(2) Is my approach for option (B) and option (C) correct?

Comment: please help me in this.

Comment: for option (C) consider $g(x)=xf'(x)$ and since $g(3/2)=0=g(7/4)$ then according to Rolle's theorem there exist at least one $c\in (\frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{4})$ such that $g'(c)=0$ $\implies$ $f'(c)+cf''(c)=0$